# How could I unit test a function which uses SqlKata?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, sqlkata

How could I unit test a function which uses [SqlKata](https://sqlkata.com/docs/)?

I am using the `QueryFactory` to create and execute queries and as I can see there is neither interface for it, nor any of the methods are virtual. Meaning, I can not mock the results and behavior of the `QueryFactory`, `Query` and the the methods like `Where`, `Select`, `WhereIn`, etc.

So, if I have a method which uses SqlKata I have no idea how to mock the SqlKata dependencies. Ergo, I can not test it. Hope someone knows how to mock the SqlKata and could share that knowledge, hence the question.

May there be any reasons that low level ORMs are not supposed to be mocked? And as a result the SqlKata developers did not put interfaces/virtual members in the library.

Comment: if there's nothing to be mocked, there's nothing to be mocked. End of the story. You can however try to create some in-memory database (no idea if Kata supports that). So in fact you're still testing for a database, but the database is completely within the control of your test.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, but I was not able to find anything explaining that statement on the internet. I.e. I was not able to find an official (or even a non official) recommendations not to unit test the logic written with SqlKata. Though, I agree with you - it feels as if I can do nothing about it.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, I like the idea with the in memory database, thanks.

Comment: Hi @manymanymore, Ahmad here author of SqlKata, could you please elaborate more, happy to get your feedback on this

Comment: @amd, how could I mock results of the SqlKata execution?

Comment: Does using an inmemory SQLite provider in test works for you?
https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution#sqlite

Comment: @amd, not exactly. Because, it is exponentially harder to create an in memory database and prepopulate it, than it is to just mock a return value of a method.

Comment: @manymanymore I agree, in this case the only thing I would expect to be mocked is the `.Get()`, `.Insert()`, etc... methods since mocking the Query Builder methods makes no sense, is this correct?

Comment: @amd, almost all the projects I was working on were using the [Moq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/visual-studio-toolbox/unit-testing-moq-framework). The Moq will fail if an unmocked member on a mocked instance is accessed. So, something has to be done about the query builder as well.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback, I will take this into consideration, I you have more details, I appreciate if you create a ticket so we can roll it faster

Comment: @amd, I just left this part untested in my project. Thank you for the quick response, I appreciate it. I think your quick response makes the library better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have just wrote my own this code (using xUnit):

```
var mockQF = new Mock<QueryFactory>();
string p1 = "my condition value";
mockQF.Setup(_db => _db.Query("MyTable").Where("p1", p1)).Returns(new SqlKata.Query());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).